# retrieving two separate tables in one query sql procedure c#

Tags: c#, sql, procedure

heres my sql query :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GET_SAMEDATE ( @FileName nvarchar(max) )   AS
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Hash 
FROM   Beamer.PackageDetailFile DF(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Beamer.PackageDetail D (NOLOCK) ON DF.PackageDetailId = D.Id
INNER JOIN Beamer.Package P (NOLOCK) ON D.PackageId = P.Id 
WHERE  FileName = @FileName AND P.EnvRelationId=3 AND P.IsPublished=1
ORDER  BY Date DESC
```

what i want to do is, i also want to select the Date from that table, but when i do that i cannot call them in another class(read them separately).

```
try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
       SqlDataReader sdr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

          while (sdr.Read())       
            {                   

              string h = (string)sdr.GetString(0);                     

              if (hash != h)
            {

                exists = true;
                Class2 bala = new Class2();
                bala.dbconnection3(FileName);

            }

                 sdr.Read();
        }
```

what i mean is i want to read the tables separately, but get them in one procedure.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a sproc which returns twee results.
2. Tell your sqldatareader to open the second result by:

> sdr.NextResult();